# Create a new column as the lowest value within other columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe such as :

```
tab
  Groups Species evalue bits NAME
1     G1     SP1   1.00  120    A
2     G1     SP1   0.50  130    B
3     G1     SP2   1.20  100    C
4     G1     SP3   0.02  190    X
5     G1     SP3   0.00  390    Z
6     G1     SP3   0.00  400    Y
7     G2     SP1   2.20   67    B
8     G2     SP1   2.10   69    A
```

And I would like within each `Groups` & `Species` to add a new column called `consensus_NAME` which is the `NAME` value with the lowest `evalue` & the highest `bits` column values.

Here I should then get ;

```
tab
  Groups Species evalue bits NAME consensus_NAME
1     G1     SP1   1.00  120    A B
2     G1     SP1   0.50  130    B B
3     G1     SP2   1.20  100    C C
4     G1     SP3   0.02  190    X Y
5     G1     SP3   0.00  390    Z Y
6     G1     SP3   0.00  400    Y Y
7     G2     SP1   2.20   67    B A
8     G2     SP1   2.10   69    A A
```

So fare I tried :

```
tab %>% filter(NAME != "") %>%
  group_by(Groups,Species) %>%
  top_n(-1,1, evalue,bits) %>%
  distinct(consensus_NAME = NAME) %>%
  right_join(tab)
```

Here is the dataframe:

```
dput(tab)
structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("G1", "G2"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("SP1", "SP2", "SP3"), class = "factor"), 
    evalue = c(1, 0.5, 1.2, 0.02, 0, 0, 2.2, 2.1), bits = c(120L, 
    130L, 100L, 190L, 390L, 400L, 67L, 69L), NAME = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "X", 
    "Y", "Z"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: What if the row with the highest `evalue` is not the row with the lowest `bits`?

Comment: Sorry -- I mean "lowest `evalue`...highest `bits`". The point is that the two conditions may not coincide. The two answers you have so far give the same results for your sample data but would give different results in other cases.

Comment: Is it always guaranteed that max  `bits` value would have min `evalue` for a group? What happens when max bits value is row 2 and min `evalue` is on row 1? Which value do you select in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the desired result, but (as noted in my comment) it prioritizes `evalue` over `bits`.

```r
tab <- structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("G1", "G2"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("SP1", "SP2", "SP3"), class = "factor"), 
    evalue = c(1, 0.5, 1.2, 0.02, 0, 0, 2.2, 2.1), bits = c(120L, 
    130L, 100L, 190L, 390L, 400L, 67L, 69L), NAME = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "X", 
    "Y", "Z"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

library(tidyverse)
tab %>% 
  filter(NAME != "") %>%
  group_by(Groups,Species) %>%
  arrange(evalue, desc(bits)) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  select(Groups, Species, consensus_NAME = NAME) %>% 
  right_join(tab, by = c("Groups", "Species")) %>% 
  relocate(consensus_NAME, .after = NAME)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 6
#> # Groups:   Groups, Species [4]
#>   Groups Species evalue  bits NAME  consensus_NAME
#>   <fct>  <fct>    <dbl> <int> <fct> <fct>         
#> 1 G1     SP1       1      120 A     B             
#> 2 G1     SP1       0.5    130 B     B             
#> 3 G1     SP2       1.2    100 C     C             
#> 4 G1     SP3       0.02   190 X     Y             
#> 5 G1     SP3       0      390 Z     Y             
#> 6 G1     SP3       0      400 Y     Y             
#> 7 G2     SP1       2.2     67 B     A             
#> 8 G2     SP1       2.1     69 A     A
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I think that the cleanest way is to use `group_by` in combination with `mutate` and evaluate the desired conditions within the groups:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

t <- structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                         2L), .Label = c("G1", "G2"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                               1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("SP1", "SP2", "SP3"), class = "factor"), 
                    evalue = c(1, 0.5, 1.2, 0.02, 0, 0, 2.2, 2.1), bits = c(120L, 
                                                                            130L, 100L, 190L, 390L, 400L, 67L, 69L), NAME = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                        2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "X", 
                                                                                                                                                                                "Y", "Z"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -8L))
t %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  group_by(Groups, Species) %>% 
  mutate(
    consensus_name = NAME[bits == max(bits) & evalue == min(evalue) ]
  )
#> # A tibble: 8 x 6
#> # Groups:   Groups, Species [4]
#>   Groups Species evalue  bits NAME  consensus_name
#>   <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <int> <chr> <chr>         
#> 1 G1     SP1       1      120 A     B             
#> 2 G1     SP1       0.5    130 B     B             
#> 3 G1     SP2       1.2    100 C     C             
#> 4 G1     SP3       0.02   190 X     Y             
#> 5 G1     SP3       0      390 Z     Y             
#> 6 G1     SP3       0      400 Y     Y             
#> 7 G2     SP1       2.2     67 B     A             
#> 8 G2     SP1       2.1     69 A     A
Created on 2021-07-19 by the reprex package (v2.0.0)
```

This code is only robust, if `evalue` and `bits` are always `min` and `max`.

For example:

```
t[2,4] <- 110
```

The code will break.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(tab,
          tab %>% 
            group_by(Groups, Species) %>% 
            mutate(diff = bits - evalue) %>% 
            filter(diff == max(diff)) %>% 
            select(Groups, NAME) %>% 
            rename(consensus_NAME = NAME),
          by = c("Groups" = "Groups", "Species" = "Species"))
```

Output:

```
  Groups Species evalue bits NAME consensus_NAME
1     G1     SP1   1.00  120    A              B
2     G1     SP1   0.50  130    B              B
3     G1     SP2   1.20  100    C              C
4     G1     SP3   0.02  190    X              Y
5     G1     SP3   0.00  390    Z              Y
6     G1     SP3   0.00  400    Y              Y
7     G2     SP1   2.20   67    B              A
8     G2     SP1   2.10   69    A              A
```